# Type safety doesn't work with Angular dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, type-safety

I lose typing when I use Angular's dependency injection. I don't know why? Can someone explain and find a solution to use DI while having strict typing? I'm using a service to strictly type local storage, here's some context:

I use a class with a generic type.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService<T> implements iStorageService<T> {
// ...

  constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE_NAMESPACE) private namespace: string) {}


  set<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
    if (this.storage) {
      this.storage.setItem(
        this.namespace + key.toString(),
        JSON.stringify(value)
      );
    }
  }

// ...
}
```

and at consumer level :

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCAL_STORAGE_NAMESPACE,
      useValue: 'dumbnamespace',
    },
    LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>,
  ],
```

I tried too :

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'LocalStorageService',
      useFactory: () => new LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>('namespace'),
    },
  ],
```

with LocalStorageModel :

```
interface LocalStorageModel {
  [LocalStorageKey.Name]: string;
}
```

And in the component :

```
  private testTypeChecking = inject(LocalStorageService).set(LocalStorageKey.City, 22);
```

No error here when it should be :(

Doing it this way works (we have an error, number is not a string), but without using Angular's DI.

```
const testTypeChecking = () => {
  const localStorageService = new LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>('id');
  localStorageService.set(LocalStorageKey.Name, 22);
};
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the generic parameter isn't specified so this is expected

```
private localStorage = inject<LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>>(LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>)
// VS
constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService<LocalStorageModel>) {}
```